# Jenkins build.xml disappears from build location

Tags: jenkins

I appear to be having an inconsistency with my some, not all, of my Jenkins projects. On occasion it would appear that my build.xml is removed/deleted from the build location therefore causing the project not to build.

The more odd facet of this issue seems to be that it may well run this project fine on it's next attempt.

If anybody has any ideas as to why i may be experiencing this issue or any suggestions i would very grateful for the advice. I have googled and searched stackoverflow for similar issues and i can't find anything that seems similar.

My builds are purely triggering batch operations.

Here is a snippet of the log:

> INFO: Started Out of order build detection
>   ?[33mApr 23, 2014 7:09:27 AM jenkins.diagnostics.ooom.Problem$Inspector scan
>   WARNING: Failed to inspect C:\Users\tdrive.jenkins\jobs\Main_Trunk_Sanity_Check
>   _RokDoc\builds\2014-03-21_18-00-35: C:\Users\tdrive.jenkins\jobs\Main_Trunk_San
>   ity_Check_RokDoc\builds\2014-03-21_18-00-35\build.xml doesn't exist
>   ?[0m?[33mApr 23, 2014 7:09:27 AM jenkins.diagnostics.ooom.Problem$Inspector scan

Answer (score 0):

How is your workspace managed? Is it under SVN? Is your job doing SVN update everytime?

Comment: Hi Slav, actually my workspace is managed manually. The reason for this is that i call a number of batch files to execute an application that calls automated tests from an MS SQL database.

Comment: I have looked at some posts where it states I can set the build.xml location but I am unable to find where this is either in the Jenkins configuration or from within the actual Projects I am building.

Comment: Setting the `build.xml` location is probably for `ant` builds. The `build.xml` that you are talking about, at least in your log snippet, is the actual Jenkins job configuration file. You don't really change that, unless you reconfigure where Jenkins's home directory is and/or relative workspace location within that.

Comment: I did think this was something I could not configure. I have not made a change to the path for the Jenkins home directory. This is a really odd scenario made harder by the fact it is not consistent in any manner. As i say the other confusing aspect is how a certain project may actually run on the next occasion. Thanks for your help and time so far Slav